# Efficient way to print the N first permutations of an array of N Elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby, memory, permutation, out-of-memory

The thing I need to do is very simple, so I don't need to create a complex program and I only need to use this once, making the result of this the feed data for the real project I'm working now.

I need to obtain the 50 first (or, better, 50 randoms) combinations of a set of N elements, being N every value from 2 to 50.

In Ruby, logically, will be something like

```
require 'pp'

pp (1..50).to_a.permutation.to_a.first(50)
```

But sadly, that programs always ran out of memory. As I matter of fact, the "maximum" number I could generate on my machine is  10, and I need 50.

I'm pretty sure that exists some other, more efficient way, to achieve this, but because I don't know very well the maths involved, I need to desperately ask for you help. Any of you know about some gem, library, or even an algorithm who do that in a way that doesn't consume all the memory. It doesn't matter if is slow, as I said, I only need to generate this thing once.

Comment: can you add a sample of your permutation method?

Comment: The permutation I use is a standard method of the Array Class on the Ruby Standard Classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `to_a` on the permutation enumerator, just use it as an enumerator:

```
(1..50).to_a.permutation.first(50)
```

But if you want random permutations, you can just shuffle the array 50 times:

```
ar = (1..50).to_a
Array.new(50){ar.shuffle}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`#take`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) method of Enumerable:

```
pp (1..50).to_a.permutation.take(50)
```

Comment: you could add `shuffle` to get random ones: `(1..50).to_a.shuffle.permutation.take(50)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to iterate and generate the arrays one at a time to prevent memory issues. e.g.

```
1.upto(50) do |i|
  store permutions_for i
end

def permutions_for(size)
  #get permutions for the given size
end

def store(arr)
  # print, save to db, whatever, just don't keep it in memory :)
end
```